# MSAL idToken does not have upn, profile or email data? need it in idToken for passport-azure-ad authorization

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, passport-azure-ad

I have an angular8 app using the official msal package [(not the one for angular, the main one)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) on the backend I'm authorizing using [passport-azure-ad (official microsoft package)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-ad)

I need to have the user's email address in the IdToken as I can't validate with bearer strategy against access token. I need some way to get that email address either through the UPN or directly.

I have tried 4 different accounts under different AD groups and so far only for 1 AD group it has actually showed an 'email' OR 'upn' field in the idToken.

[Permissions configured in the app screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ffT.png)

The options of the login request:

```
  private loginRequest: Msal.AuthenticationParameters = {
    scopes: ['user.read', 'email', 'profile', 'openid'],
    extraScopesToConsent: ['email']
  };
```

I have tried any variation I can think of, I tried having them starting with capital leters (Email, User.Read) like in the screenshot, I've tried swapping them around scopes & extraScopesToConsent, I've tried putting 'upn' anywhere but no luck.

Would it be possible to either:

A: Get that data somehow in the token
B: Get another token I can validate as 'bearer token' with my backend that has that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending the email in the req body from frontend, then updated my passport strategy to use the request object.